# Conditional statements using np.where and np.select

Tags: python, numpy, boolean, conditional-statements

Trying to populate a column in a dataframe based on whether certain strings are present in a different column.  I can do it with a series of nested `np.where` statements such as:

```
cond1=df.CollectType.str.contains('Outcrop')
cond2=df.CollectType.str.contains('Chip channel')
cond3=df.CollectType.str.contains('Rubble')
cond4=df.CollectType.str.contains('Float')
cond5=df.CollectType.str.contains('Dump')

df['R_SampleType'] = np.where(cond1, 'Outcrop', np.where(cond2, 
  'Chip channel', np.where(cond3,'Rubble', 
                           np.where(cond4,'Float', 
                                    np.where(cond5,'Dump','')))))
```

But this doesn't seem very efficient.  So, I'm trying to list the conditions and call the list with:

```
 values = ['Outcrop', 'Chip Channel','Rubble','Float','Dump']
 conditions = list(map(df['CollectType'].str.contains, values))

 df['R_SampleType'] = np.select(conditions, values, '')
```

But I get the error:

```
ValueError: invalid entry 0 in condlist: should be boolean ndarray
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you just want to copy a column, and put an empty string where a condition is not met.

If this is the case, here is a solution:

```
df["R_SampleType"] = df.CollectType.where(df.CollectType.isin(values_ok), other="")
```

Reproducible example:

```
from random import choices

values_ok = ["Outcrop", "Chip channel", "Rubble", "Float", "Dump"]
values_nok = ["Not", "A", "Valid", "Value"]
num_items = 15

df = pd.DataFrame(
    choices(values_ok + values_nok, k=num_items), columns=["CollectType"]
)

df["R_SampleType"] = df.CollectType.where(df.CollectType.isin(values_ok), other="")
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: what if I want to set `df["R_SampleType"]` to the string `"AllRocks"` whenever `values_ok` is true instead of seting `df["R_SampleType"]` to the value in `values_ok`

Comment: In this case, you can use `np.where` which let you choose elements for both the negative and positive cases. So something like `df["R_SampleType"] = np.where(df.CollectType.isin(values_ok), "AllRocks", "")`